# Variable Name field

Tags: apex

I have le following fields:
Gigabytes_tier_1__c

Gigabytes_tier_2__c

Gigabytes_tier_3__c

Gigabytes_tier_4__c

I would like write like this:

```
for (Integer i=1;i<5; i++) {
                     OpportunityLineItem newOpptLineItem = new OpportunityLineItem();                 
                     newOpptLineItem.Tier__c= opptInserted.Gigabytes_tier_+i+__c;
```

but it doesn't work.

Do you know how achieve this?

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

BR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also use the .get method of an sObject with a fieldname.
So something like this

```
String fieldName = 'Gigabytes_tier_' + i + '__c';
newOpptLineItem.Tier__c = (Decimal)opptInserted.get(fieldName);  //cast the result to the appropriate datatype
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but with your solution i'm getting an error:  Illegal assignment from Object to Decimal,which is the problem? Thanks again

Comment: You need to cast the result to the appropriate data type - I've updated the answer to illustrate